# More Efficient Method of Drawing Thousands of Particles (Java/Android)

Tags: java, android, optimization, draw, particles

So I'm writing a sort of particle simulator, like a "falling sand game" if you know what that is, and I've kind of hit a roadblock now. The way I'm doing this is I have a particle object that basically as of now has an position (int x, int y) and that's it. The way I'm drawing/moving them, is with a thread and the onDraw event for an android panel. Each time onDraw is called I loop through all the particles, move them down one pixel unless they hit the bottom and then draw them, this is pretty smooth until I get to about 200 particles, then the fps drops significantly. I know this is computation heavy the way I'm doing it, there's no debate about it, but is there any way I could do this to allow a lot more particles to be drawn and with less lag?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I take it you're using an individual-pixel drawing function for this? That would indeed be slow.

I see a couple ways to improve it. First is to put the pixels into an in-memory bitmap then draw the whole bitmap at the same time. Second, since particles are always just going down one pixel, you can scroll part of the bitmap instead of replotting everything. If Android doesn't have a scroll then just draw the bitmap one pixel down and start a new bitmap for the particles above the scroll. You'll have to fix up the particles on the bottom, but there are fewer of those.

Comment: it's android's drawPoint(x,y,Paint) function.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into [OpenGL ES](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) hardware acceleration and [renderscript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/renderscript.html).  It doesn't give you a more efficient solution code wise (see the other answers for that).  It does open up a lot more processing power for you to use however.  You can even run the entire simulation on the GPU (possibly, don't know your implementation details).

**Edit**
Also, if you still decide to do the processing in java, you should look at [Method Profiling in DDMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html#using-ddms).  This will help you visualize where your performance bottlenecks are.

Comment: +1: Really, the only reasonable answer here. OpenGL is designed exactly to do this kind of processing.

Answer (score 2):

I've never done things like this before, but I have done some complex *cellular automata*. Sorry if this is too vague.

The basic idea here is to **mark** all particles that should "keep falling" or "not move" and **exclude** them from complex processing (with a special **short/fast** processor for the "falling" list - all you need to do is drop each one by a pixel).

- The acceleration for non-moving particles - static particles (I'll call them S particles), is that they don't move. Mark it for all non-moving regions (like a gravity-immune "wall" or "bowl" that a user might make. Mark particles above it S if they are stable, so for example for liquid, *if it has S particles under, and to both sides of itself, it will not move*. For something like sand that forms piles, *if it has an S in each of the three spots under it*, it makes a pile, you'll get nice 45-degree piles like this, I'm sure you can change it to make some things form steeper, or less-steep piles. Do S mapping bottom-up.
- The acceleration for particles with no particle under them is falling - F particles. Particles with an F particle under them are also F particles. Mark these bottom-up as well.
- Particles unmarked F or S are **complex**, they may start falling, stop falling, or roll, use the slow processor, which you already have, to deal with them, there shouldn't be many.

In the end what you will have is many many fast particles. Those in a pile/lake and those raining down. The leftover particles are those on the edge of slopes, on the top of lakes, or in other complex positions. There shouldn't be nearly as many as there will be fast particles.

**Visually mark** each kind of particle with some colour, complex particles being bright red. Find cases where it is still slow, and see *what other kinds of fast processors* you should make. For example you may find that making lots of piles of sand creates lots of red areas along slopes, you may want to invest in speeding up "rolling zones" along the slopes of piles.

Hope it makes sense. Don't forget to come back and edit once you've figured something out!

Comment: this is very helpful, I'll probably do this

Answer (score 0):

If you blur your image a bit, then you could just move half particule at a time, maybe one fourth only and print them all.. that would cut computation and the user wouldn't see it, getting the feeling all particules move.

But what ever you choose, I think you should be put a strong limit, not all users have powerfull android devices.

Regards, 
 stéphane

Answer (score 0):

I think if particles are close each other, you can create objects that represent 3 or more particles.

When displaying several particles on screen, sets of grains maybe gets unnoticed.